# Copy file from remote server through lftp

Tags: linux, unix, ssl, lftp

I'm new to linux scripting. I want to copy file from remote server to current server(executing or client server),required cert & key files are already installed on my server(client server). below commands work when I execute it individually in sequence but, after Integrating into a .sh script it doesnt!

--My Script--

```
    lftp -u username,xxx -p 2121 remoteServer.net; 
    set ssl:cert-file /abc/def/etc/User_T.p12;    
    set ssl:key-file abc/def/etc/User_T.p12.pwd;    
    lftp -e 'set net:timeout 10; get /app/home/atm/feed.txt -o /com/data/';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt"? No action at all or an error message (if so which one)?

Comment: It executes only first command. set ssl:cert and below command not getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

man lftp:

```
   -f script_file
          Execute commands in the file and exit.  This option must be used
          alone without other arguments (except --norc).

   -c commands
          Execute  the  given commands and exit. Commands can be separated
          with a semicolon, `&&' or `||'. Remember to quote  the  commands
          argument  properly in the shell.  This option must be used alone
          without other arguments (except --norc).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "here document" feature of the shell:

```
lftp <<EOF
set... 
open... 
get...
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks lav for your suggestion, I found that my script was not executing second line so added continuation like 
      **<<   SCRIPT** 
& ended script with **SCRIPT**
removed all semi colon... Its working